# How can I find, recursively, all files in my directory tree that first character in first line of each file is a space, a tab or a line break?

Tags: bash, awk, grep, find, regular-expression

eg:

I have two files, a.txt and b.txt:

a.txt

```
line 1
line 2
```

b.txt

```
 line 1
line 2
```

In this case b.txt should appear in the listing because the first character of first line is a space, a tab or a line break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way with **`find`** + **`awk`** command:

```
find . -type f -size +0c -exec awk '{ exit (/^[[:space:]]/? 0 : 1) }' {} \; -print
```

---

> The `exit` statement causes `awk` to immediately stop executing the
>   current rule and to stop processing input; any remaining input is
>   ignored. The exit statement is written as follows:
>
> ```
> exit [return code]
> ```
>
> If an argument is supplied to exit, its value is used as the exit status code for the `awk` process

`find`'s **`-print`** action will be executed only if `awk` process provide exit status `0`

---

A more simplified approach would be as follows:

```
find . -type f -size +0c -exec awk '{ exit (!NF? 0 : 1) }' {} \; -print
```

Comment: It works, but strangely, not for newlines.

Comment: @Lawrence, check my simplified approach

Comment: `awk` would return _true_ for empty files as well. You'd want to skip them with `-size +0c`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, ideally - yes, see my update

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest The simplified approach worked when the first character is a \n, but not when is a tab or a space. I could say your two solutions together solved my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
find . -type f -exec awk 'NR==1 && /^\s/{print FILENAME}' {} \;
```

Or using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)4 :

```
shopt -s globstar
awk 'NR==1 && /^\s/{print FILENAME} **/*
```

Comment: Note that even in the C locale, `\s` (a GNU extension) matches more than just space tab and newline.

Comment: It works, but strangely, not for newlines.

Comment: `echo  | grep '^\s'` : no output, but there's a newline

Comment: @Lawrence, because awk works line-based. So the first line (NR==1) or any other line doesn't contain newline as newline is the record separator. Here, you'd want to also check if the first line is empty.

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
starts_with_space() {
  local c
  read -ku0 c < ${1-$REPLY} && [[ $c = [$' \t\n'] ]]
}
printf '%s\n' **/*(D.L+0+starts_with_space)
```

- `D` include dot-files (hidden files) and descend into hidden dirs like `find` does.
- `.` only regular files (like `find`'s `-type f`)
- `L+0`: only non-empty files (like `find`'s `-size +0c`)
- `+starts_with_space` only those for which `starts_with_space` returns true.

One of the benefits over `find` is that it gives you a sorted list of file names. It only reads one character (possibly more than one byte in locales with multi-byte charsets) from each file.

Comment: I use bash. Could not test this solution. But hey, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solution with `awk` at end.

Using GNU `sed` (which supports exiting the `sed` script with an explicit exit status):

```
find . -type f -size +0c -exec sed -n '1{/^[^[:blank:]]/q 1};q' {} ';' -print
```

The `-size +0c` ensures that files that are completely empty are not reported.

If the current directory contains the two files from the question and an extra file `c.txt` with an empty first line, then this generates

```
./b.txt
./c.txt
```

The GNU `sed` script:

```
1{
    /^[^[:blank:]]/q 1
}
q
```

For line 1, it checks whether the first character on the line is a non-blank (not space or tab), and if it is, then it exits with exit status 1 (`q 1`).  Otherwise it exits with exit status zero (the last `q`).

An empty first line will not match `/^[^[:blank:]]/`, so that case is handled correctly.

If `sed` exits with a zero exit status, the `-print` will cause the file's pathname to be printed to standard output by `find`.

---

The equivalent thing, but using `awk` (any `awk` will do):

```
find . -type f -size +0c -exec awk '/^[^[:blank:]]/ { e=1 } { exit e }' {} ';' -print
```